# Matrix Generator python index assignment list out of range

Tags: python, matrix, indexing

Below is the code I have written. It says the list assingment index is out of range. I can't seem to figure out where I've gone wrong here. Maybe someone could elaborate as to where the error is.

```
def genarator(x, y):
    square = x * y
    matrix = [[]]
    matrix2 = []

    i = 0    
    while square > 0:
        j = 0
        while x > j:
            matrix[i][j] = int(raw_input("Enter the matrix number"))
            j = 1
        i = 1
        square = -square
        matrix2 = matrix2 + matrix

    return matrix2


def main():    
    matrix3 = []
    x = int(raw_input("Enter the width of your matrix"))
    y = int(raw_input("Enter the Length of your matrix"))
    matrix3 = genarator(x, y)
    print(matrix3)
    return 0

main()
```

###EDIT###########I SOLVED THE PROBLEM

def generator(x, y):

```
matrix = [[0 for i in range(x)] for j in range(y)]

turns = x

i = 0

j = 0

while turns > 0:

    while i < x:

        while j < y:

            matrix[i][j] = int(raw_input("Enter Array values"))

            j += 1
        j = 0

        i += 1

    turns -= 1

print(matrix)
```

def main():

```
x = int(raw_input("Enter array length"))

y = int(raw_input("Enter array width"))

print(generator(x, y))

return 0
```

main()

Answer (score 0):

If you try the following snippet:

```
x = []
x[0] = 4
```

You will see that there is an error.  The reason for this is that `x[0]` has not yet been defined, so it can not be modified.  To fix your error, you will have to append something to your list before modifying it:

```
def genarator(x, y):
    square = x * y
    matrix = [[]]
    matrix2 = []

    i = 0    
    while square > 0:
        matrix.append([])
        j = 0
        while x > j:
            matrix[-1].append(int(raw_input("Enter the matrix number")))
            j = 1
        i = 1
        square = -square
        matrix2 = matrix2 + matrix

    return matrix2
```

I also modified the indexing because `-1` will give you the last item, which is what you want.